# Setting javascript variables from html input field

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, input

This is more of a coding practice question, I want to set variables within a javascript object / array from a html form.

I am currently doing this using the onkeyup and passing the value to a set function. e.g: (along the lines of )

```
 onclick="item.setVar('retouch', this.value); return false;"

 setVar: function(variable, value){
    this[variable] = parseInt(value);
 }
```

is there a better way of doing this or is it down to personal preference.

Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: "is there a better way of doing this": please define `better`.  Better how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal preference if using vanilla Javascript, but why the function even?

```
onclick="item['retouch'] = parseInt(this.value); return false;"
```

Maybe you should look into a JS model binding library, like [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/) or [Angular](http://angularjs.org/)?